# How find last line in a Google Sheet with getRange

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the following script to find and replace text.  The only problem is in the line:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("D2:D2000");
```

It creates new rows past my last row as it is set to 2000.  I need to find the last row and then change this line of code. I'm lost :(

My total script is as follows:

```js
function runReplaceInSheet() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NK-pmvrJoSqKSgx2zRCAcRKGjk8SiiSsfwwerhfdM1SE"); // UPDATE ID
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);     // UPDATE number in square brackets


var range = sheet.getRange("D2:D2000");


//  get the current data range values as an array
//  Lesser calls to access the sheet, lower overhead 
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
var numRows = 2; // UPDATE number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 4, numRows, 1) // Numbers of rows to process
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var v = row[3]; // edit: don't need this
    var values = range.getValues();  

    // Replace Names

    replaceInSheet(values, '1', 'Active');
    replaceInSheet(values, '0', 'Inctive');

    //write the updated values to the sheet, again less call;less overhead
    range.setValues(values);        
}
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {

//loop over the rows in the array
for (var row in values) {

    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
        return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace, replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;


}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. In order to understand correctly, can I ask you about your question? You want to retrieve the last row of column "D" and run ``replaceInSheet()`` to only the retrieved last row. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is not correct, can you tell me the detail of what you want?

Comment: Thank you so very much for your reply.  Right now the way the script works is that it will run through row 1 to 2000 as I have 2000 hardcoded: var range = sheet.getRange("D2:D2000");.   

What I need to do is figure out how to change the D2000 to the last row. so something like D2:<last row>.    Otherwise my sheet it filled with 1500 empty rows below the last row.  

Does this make sense? 

THANK YOU AGAIN SO VERY MUHC!

Comment: `Sheet.getLastRow()`?

Comment: Read the Apps Script developer documentation for the `Spreadsheet` -> `Sheet` class. Or look through the available methods in the "autocomplete" that pops up after you type `sheet.` in the Script Editor

Comment: @user2393110 I'm sorry for my late reply. And thank you for replying. It seems that the solutions for your issue have already been put. So I think that they will help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sheet.getDataRange()` to return a range that describes the area of the sheet with some data in it.

If you just want column D2:d you could do this

```
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
range = range.offset (1,3,range.getNumRows()-1,1);
```

Or you could get the data into a 1 dimensional array like this

```
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1)
.map (function (d) {
    return d[3];
});
```

There are many ways.

Comment: I've tried this:

var range = sheet.getRange("D2:" & sheet.getDataRange());

but i get an error? PLEASE HELP!  As you can tell i'm not the great at javascript.